# How to clip rendering to be within a rounded border?

Tags: wpf, xaml, opacity, clipping

I'm trying to create a border with rounded corners and a highlight on its top half. I'm using an ellipse with a radial gradient, overlapping the top half of the border, to give the highlight, but I can't figure out how to prevent the ellipse coloring the corners of the border. Here's a screenshot from Kaxaml:

[image: ClipToBounds not working]

And here's the XAML code:

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Background="DarkGray">

  <Grid Width="256" Height="256">
    <Border CornerRadius="16" Background="Black" Margin="4">
      <Border Background="Gray" Margin="32">
        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="1" FontFamily="Trebuchet MS" FontSize="96pt"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
      </Border>
    </Border>
    <Border CornerRadius="16" ClipToBounds="True">
      <Ellipse>
        <Ellipse.Fill>
          <RadialGradientBrush>
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
          </RadialGradientBrush>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
          <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="3" ScaleY="2" CenterX="128" CenterY="128"/>
            <TranslateTransform Y="-235"/>
          </TransformGroup>
        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
      </Ellipse>
    </Border>
    <Border CornerRadius="16" BorderThickness="8" BorderBrush="Black"/>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

How can I stop the top corner areas being affected by the ellipse's shading?

I've tried playing around with `OpacityMask`, but I have to confess I don't really understand how to use it, especially with the ellipse being transformed for rendering. Whatever I try, the ellipse either disappears entirely or is completely unaffected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it looks fine when I compiled and run you code in Visual Studio.
Second, why do not you use this `RadialGradientBrush` as `Background` of the first `Border`? Something like this:

```
<Border CornerRadius="16" >
    <Border.Background>
        <RadialGradientBrush Center=".5 0" GradientOrigin=".5 0" RadiusX="1" >
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
        </RadialGradientBrush>
    </Border.Background>
</Border>
```

Comment: That'll teach me not to over-simplify my sample code. :( The reason I don't put the radial gradient on the border itself is that, in my actual app, the border contains other elements. The ellipse then sits over the top of both the border and its contents. Using the radial gradient as the border background would mean it's *underneath* the border's content. Sorry I wasn't clear on this.

Comment: In fact, I'll update the sample code and image to make it clearer.

Comment: Also, I'm surprised you don't get the problem in Visual Studio. To double check, I just did the same myself and the problem's still there. I'm using VS2008.

Comment: I'm gonna accept this answer, as it got me to a solution - which I'll post in a separate answer so that the code is shown with formatting. Thanks for your help, alpha-mouse.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `ClipToBounds` or `OpacityMask`, I ended up using the radial gradient as the background to an additional `Border` element. Thanks to alpha-mouse for the tip.

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Background="DarkGray">

  <Grid Width="256" Height="256">
    <Border CornerRadius="16" Background="Black" Margin="4">
      <Border Background="Gray" Margin="32">
        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="1" FontFamily="Trebuchet MS" FontSize="96pt"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
      </Border>
    </Border>
    <Border CornerRadius="16" Margin="4">
      <Border.Background>
        <RadialGradientBrush>
          <RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
            <TransformGroup>
              <ScaleTransform ScaleX="3" ScaleY="2" CenterX="128" CenterY="128"/>
              <TranslateTransform Y="-235"/>
            </TransformGroup>
          </RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
          <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
          <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
        </RadialGradientBrush>
      </Border.Background>
    </Border>
    <Border CornerRadius="16" BorderThickness="8" BorderBrush="Black"/>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

And here's the final appearance:

[image: No more little grey ears on the border]

Thanks.